# Just two cryptic clues?

Tags: cryptic-clues

My first puzzle here was literally small. Here's a puzzle that is nonliterally small

Silver, without any left, flipped it at charged particle modification (8)

Within Buddhist or Yiddish lore (7)

After solving these two cryptic clues, their answers will make a two word phrase describing what you should now see

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted by [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48623/25412),

> Solving the cryptic clues yield REVISION HISTORY, and the revision history contains the following:
>  "Silver, without any left, flipped it at charged particle modification (12)
>  Within Buddhist or Yiddish lore (5)
>  After solving these two cryptic clues, their answers will make a two word phrase describing what you just saw. "

Note that...

> The same clues are there, with different enumerations. The answers are probably:
>  REVISITATION: SI(-L)VER flipped+IT+AT+ION , def: modification(?)
>  STORY: Hidden in Buddhi**st or Y**iddish, def: lore

So the final(?) answer is

> **Revisitation story.**

Comment: Revisitation meaning modification is too much of a stretch to me. Of course, you could be right. But, it just feels odd.

Comment: It is correct, but I see where you're coming from Sid. I tried to get something partially between "revision", "revisitation", and the element-y theme of the clue but I didn't find anything that fit real well

Answer (score 5):

Silver, without any left, flipped it at charged particle modification (8)

> **REVISION**. Silver without "l"(@Ankoganit points out that, L is an abbreviation of Left), Reversed, charades with ION. Modification-Def. (@TechIdiot found it, but I had figured it out independently as well)

Within Buddhist or Yiddish lore (7)

> **HISTORY**- Charade. I am not sure, lore=history but it sounds okay. @Yandrakus points out that Within clues Charade.

SO, now,

> We have to see the revision history, where we see strange things in the original post.

Comment: Yes, lore relates to myths/stories/tales.

Comment: Maybe the clue is WITHIN:
Buddhist or Yiddish --> Budd - HIST - OR - Y - iddish

HISTORY is within the two words

Comment: L is an abbreviation for left (without any left).

Comment: @Ankoganit Ah, Yes. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 4):

Silver, without any left, flipped it at charged particle modification (8)

> Silver, without any left -> SI<s>L</s>VER -> REVIS(flipped) + at Charged Particle -> ION  -> **REVISION**(def. Modification)

Within Buddhist or Yiddish lore (7)

> **HISTORY**. Already solved by [@Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48623/30887)